# Suppose that $\vert h_k^{\prime}\vert \leq 1/2$ prove that $F_n$ tends to a constant

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Given a sequence of differentiable $h_k:\mathbb{R}^m\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ $k=0,1,2,...$

Suppose that $\vert h_k^{\prime}\vert \leq 1/2$ prove that $F_k=h_k\circ\cdots\circ h_2 \circ h_1$ converges uniformly to application constant.

> Thanks to the comments note that missing a test condition ..but that hypothesis  should be added on the succession $h_k$?

Any hints would be appreciated.

From the condition using the Weierstrass M-T, has $\sum F_k^{\prime}$ converges uniformly, then $F_k^{\prime}$ converges to zero uniformly. I want to apply the mean value theorem, but my test case only restricted to bounded.

Comment: sorry .. edited!

Comment: You need some further condition. As is, $h_k(x) = (k,0,\dotsc,0)$ provides a counterexample.

Comment: and when $k>m$ as defined $h_k=?$

Comment: $m$ plays no role. All $h_k$ are constant, with the first component of the image being $k$, and the $m-1$ other components $0$.

Comment: correct!!  that condition would fail?

Comment: @helmonio: You need that $F_k$ converges at some point. Using the mean value theorem you can conclude convergence everywhere and then you get that the limit is constant.

Comment: @ Jose27: I think he wants to apply a convergence criterion derived, but the convegencia is uniform if the domain $U$ is bounded.. how could you do this to $R^m$